# Android - Strange ListView bug

Tags: android, listview

An ArrayList holds string values in the following order: "GREEN", "GREEN", "RED", "RED", "GREEN", "GREEN". The values are correctly displayed in the ListView of the ListActivity.

I've set it so that when any item in the ListView is clicked, all items with string value "RED" are deleted from the list. However, the problem is that the ListView, despite its value container now only containing "GREEN" values, visually shows the removal of two "GREEN" values, so now the ListView shows "GREEN", "GREEN", "RED", "RED", even though the adapter contains the values "GREEN", "GREEN", "GREEN", "GREEN.

If the adapter contains the values R, R, G, G, R, R, G, G and an item is clicked, it now contains R, R, G, G.

Is there an error in my code? The debugger showing all "GREEN" string values is really perplexing because the ListView is showing something different.

```
public class MyActivity extends ListActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    ArrayList<String> listValues;
    bugtestadapter adapter;

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        listValues = new ArrayList<String>();
        listValues.add("GREEN");
        listValues.add("GREEN");
        listValues.add("RED");
        listValues.add("RED");
        listValues.add("GREEN");
        listValues.add("GREEN");

        adapter = new bugtestadapter(this, R.layout.adapter, listValues);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        deleteRedValues();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void deleteRedValues() {
        for (Iterator<String> iterator = listValues.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            String c = iterator.next();
            if (c.equals("RED")) {
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

bugtestadapter.java

```
public class bugtestadapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    Context mContext;
    ArrayList<String> adapterList;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public bugtestadapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<String> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        mContext = context;
        adapterList = (ArrayList)objects;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if ( convertView == null ) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate( R.layout.adapter, null );
            TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.adapterItem);
            tv.setText(adapterList.get(position));

            if (tv.getText().equals("GREEN"))
                tv.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            else if (tv.getText().equals("RED"))
                tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: clear your list adapter

Comment: Clearing the list adapter clears all the values. I'm only trying to remove "RED" values. The issue here is that the container holds only "GREEN" values, but the ListView is showing "RED" values that were deleted.

Comment: ...and if convertView is not  null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In getView method initialize the views in the If condition i.e., if(convertView==null) and set teh data outside of the loop.

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
Holder holder;
        if ( convertView == null ) {
holder=new Holder();
                convertView = inflater.inflate( R.layout.adapter, null );
                holder.tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.adapterItem);
            }else{
holder=convertView.getTag();
}

tv.setText(adapterList.get(position));
            if (tv.getText().equals("GREEN"))
                tv.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            else if (tv.getText().equals("RED"))
                tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        return convertView;
    }
```

and add an Holder to it.

```
private class Holder{
TextView tvName;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I'm understanding what's happening. Once you set a views value and it gets saved with holder, it reuses that value if it needs to. Thus, the text value for a view for a certain position within the holder is still set to whatever text it was set to already.

Comment: yes. Once list item goes invisible by scrolling the listview that item will be reused without creating a new view thus it gains speed and saves memory.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it with **Holder** class like below:

```
public class bugtestadapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    Context mContext;
    ArrayList<String> adapterList;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public bugtestadapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<String> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        mContext = context;
        adapterList = (ArrayList)objects;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if ( convertView == null ) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate( R.layout.adapter, null );
            holder.tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.adapterItem);
            holder.tv.setText(adapterList.get(position));

            if (holder.tv.getText().equals("GREEN"))
                holder.tv.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            else if (tv.getText().equals("RED"))
                holder.tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }


        return convertView;
    }

class ViewHolder {
            TextView tv;

        }
}
```

Comment: I usually use the holder class, but I was trying to shorten the example. Using a ViewHolder doesn't solve the problem. Thanks though.